# Something wrong with my binary converter

Tags: c++

I have been learning C++ for about a month. And I made a binary converter. But when I input a large number,such as 200000000,it will return a wrong answer. So I changed all `int` into `double` and changed some codes,but it was still wrong.Then I searched for the solution on Google,but I got nothing. Please point out my mistake!Thanks! Below is the code.

(Sorry for my poor English and it's my first time asking a question on this website.If I made anything wrong,please point it out and forgive me.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    double m,n,t,x,i=0;
    cin>>n;
    m=n;
    do{
        if(fmod(n,2)==0) n/=2;
        else n=(n-1)/2;
        i++;
    }while(n>=1);
    for(t=0;t<i;t++){
        x+=fmod(m,2)*pow(10,t);
        if(fmod(m,2)==0) m/=2;
        else m=(m-1)/2;
    }
    printf("%.f\n",x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `double` is the wrong variable type for this. You Need to use `long` or `long long`

Comment: First rule of floating-point - nobody talk.. no, nobody uses floating point unless they have to.

Comment: What is your maximum number that you need to convert?

Comment: Every primitive data type has a maximum value. Using a bigger type is just a workaround. I recommend you research ways of detecting input strings that represent values which are too high. Try to write a program which behaves nicely (e.g. printing an error message) if I enter "100000000000000000000000000000".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change `double` to `unsigned long long` but it won't help because of the following code.

```
        x+=fmod(m,2)*pow(10,t);
        if(fmod(m,2)==0) m/=2;
        else m=(m-1)/2;
```

This code converts `m` to decimal so that it can be printed. But since it shifts ones by powers of 10 it goes beyond the range of even `unsigned long long`.

It can be fixed by declaring `x` as a `string`. Change `fmod` to `%`.

And

```
    x+=fmod(m,2)*pow(10,t);
```

to

```
x = ((m%2)? "1":"0") + x ;
```

and `cout << x << endl;` at the end. Good luck!

Comment: In the world of integers, `if(fmod(m,2)==0) m/=2; else m=(m-1)/2;` is reduced to `m /= 2;`

Comment: Thanks!It really helped me a lot!